# Сбился весь интерфейс Qt creator

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Сбился весь интерфейс Qt creator подскажите как вернуться к первоночальному состоянию

Comment: Как обычно `Ctrl+z`

Comment: если винда, то удаляйте файлы из `C:\Users\имя\AppData\Roaming\QtProject`, если линукс `~/.config/QtProject`